# Bootstrap container gets margin-top 0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Why does my `.container main_container` div hang on the header? (Its not because the 2 php error message, i tried)

If i give the div about `100px margin-top`, it will be okay, but that isn't a good method.

After the header, I added a `clearfix` div, but it did nothing.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ov5Lxb34/)

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top mainHeader">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $host; ?>"><?php echo $siteName; ?></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <?php
        $top_menuDown = mysqli_query($kapcs, "SELECT * FROM top_menu WHERE top_menu_id IN (1,3,4,5,6,7) ORDER BY top_menu_sorrend ASC");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($top_menuDown) > 0 )
        {
            while($top_nav = mysqli_fetch_assoc($top_menuDown))
            {
                echo '<li><a class="top_menu_to_link" href="'.$host.'/'.$top_nav['top_menu_seo'].'" title="'.$top_nav['top_menu_nev'].'">'.$top_nav['top_menu_nev'].'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use `navbar-fixed-top` class in your navbar. That's a Bootstrap class which makes your navbar `position: fixed` in CSS. Therefore you have to add `margin-top` or `padding-top` to your `main_container`. Clearfix has nothing to do with your issue in this case. When you use `position: fixed` browser get this element out of the normal document flow.

`position: absolute/fixed:`

> The element is removed from the flow of the document and other elements will behave as if it’s not even there whilst all the other positional properties will work on it.

Comment: Thank you, i deleted the fixed class from the html, i dont need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `padding-top/margin-top` to the body element. The reason is explained by @makshh. So just try to customize it based on screen size using Javascript.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ov5Lxb34/2/)

**Here is an example**--

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(".navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.mainHeader").height() > 100) {
    $("html, body").css("padding-top", "150px");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Főoldal</title>


<body style="padding-top:100px;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top mainHeader">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://kemenyem.hu">Nemzeti Reptéri Parkoló</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a class="top_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/" title="Kezdőlap">Kezdőlap</a></li>
          <li><a class="top_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/informaciok" title="Információk">Információk</a></li>
          <li><a class="top_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/erdekessegek" title="Hírek, érdekességek">Hírek, érdekességek</a></li>
          <li><a class="top_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kapcsolat" title="Kapcsolat">Kapcsolat</a></li>
          <li><a class="top_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/arlista" title="Árlista">Árlista</a></li>
          <li><a class="top_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/galeria" title="Galéria">Galéria</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="container main_container">
    <div class="homepage_slideshow hidden-xs">
      <div class="home-slider-wrapper hidden-xs">
        <ul class="bxslider">
          <li><img src="https://kemenyem.hu/images/homepage_slideshow/93-3.jpg" title="Teszt kép 1" alt="Teszt kép 1" /></li>
          <li><img src="https://kemenyem.hu/images/homepage_slideshow/393-1.jpg" title="Teszt kép 2" alt="Teszt kép 2" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Slider end-->
    <div class="col-md-9 left_side">
      <div class="left_title_div">
        <h3 class="left_title">Parkolóhely foglalás online</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3><strong>A megrendel&eacute;s, &aacute;raj&aacute;nlatk&eacute;r&eacute;s&nbsp;menete</strong></h3>

        <p>Amennyiben &aacute;raj&aacute;nlatot szeretne k&eacute;rni, azt a term&eacute;kekn&eacute;l a &quot;M&eacute;g jobb &aacute;rat szeretn&eacute;k&quot; gombra, vagy a men&uuml;ben az &quot;Aj&aacute;nlatk&eacute;r&eacute;s&quot; men&uuml;pontra
          val&oacute; kattint&aacute;ssal&nbsp;teheti meg.</p>

        <p>A megjelenő aj&aacute;nlatk&eacute;rő ablakban / oldalon k&eacute;rj&uuml;k t&ouml;ltse ki az &ouml;sszes mezőt, &eacute;s k&uuml;ldje el r&eacute;sz&uuml;nkre.</p>

        <p>Munkat&aacute;rsaink 2 munkanapon bel&uuml;l felveszik &Ouml;nnel a kapcsolatot az &Ouml;n &aacute;ltal megadott el&eacute;rhetős&eacute;gek valamelyik&eacute;n.</p>

        <h3><strong>Fizet&eacute;s</strong></h3>

        <p>Megrendel&eacute;s&eacute;t előre utal&aacute;ssal, vagy szem&eacute;lyesen valamelyik telephely&uuml;nk&ouml;n k&eacute;szp&eacute;nzzel tudja fizetni. A budapesti telephely&uuml;nk&ouml;n lehetős&eacute;g van bankk&aacute;rty&aacute;s fizet&eacute;sre
          is.</p>

        <h3><strong>Sz&aacute;ll&iacute;t&aacute;s</strong></h3>

        <p>A r&eacute;szletes sz&aacute;ll&iacute;t&aacute;si inform&aacute;ci&oacute;kat megtekintheti a &quot;Sz&aacute;ll&iacute;t&aacute;s&quot; men&uuml;pontban.</p>

        <h3><strong>&Aacute;rak</strong></h3>

        <p>A weboldalon felt&uuml;ntetett &aacute;rak gy&aacute;ri &aacute;rak, tartalmazz&aacute;k a 27% &Aacute;F&Aacute;-t, de nem tartalmazz&aacute;k a raklapok d&iacute;j&aacute;t, a sz&aacute;ll&iacute;t&aacute;st, &eacute;s a lerak&aacute;st.</p>
      </div>


      <div class="left_title_div">
        <h3 class="left_title">Legfrissebb hírek</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="news_box news_list">
        <div class="row main_hir_box">
          <div class="col-md-3 main_hir_box_thumb_div">
            <a href="https://kemenyem.hu/hir/13/jobb-lett-az" title="Jobb lett az instant futtatás az új Android Studio 2.3-ban" class="main_hir_img_link"><img src="https://kemenyem.hu/images/news/th_remy-metailler-hafjell_147-82712.jpg" class="img-responsive main_hir_img imageHoverOpacity" alt="Jobb lett az instant futtatás az új Android Studio 2.3-ban"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9 main_hir_box_data_div">
            <h2 class="main_hir_title_list"><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/hir/13/jobb-lett-az" title="Jobb lett az instant futtatás az új Android Studio 2.3-ban" class="main_hir_title_link_list">Jobb lett az instant futtatás az új Android Studio 2.3-ban</a></h2>
            <span class="main_hir_box_date">HÍREK | 2017-03-15 16:27</span>
            <p class="main_hir_box_desc">A Google a napokban új kiadást jelentett be integrált mobilos fejlesztőkörnyezetéből. Az új Android Studio 2.3 sok stabilitási fejlesztés mellett néhány érdekes funkcionális fejlesztést is hoz, amik az app-ok tervezését, tesztelését és a bennük
              történő hibakeresést egyaránt segítik majd.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row main_hir_box">
          <div class="col-md-3 main_hir_box_thumb_div">
            <a href="https://kemenyem.hu/hir/12/igy-fejleszthetsz-egy-php-sql-alkalmazast-git-tel-az-azure-ba" title="Így fejleszthetsz egy PHP-SQL alkalmazást Git-tel az Azure-ba 2" class="main_hir_img_link"><img src="https://kemenyem.hu/images/news/thumb_ne-style-001-2532861600.jpg" class="img-responsive main_hir_img imageHoverOpacity" alt="Így fejleszthetsz egy PHP-SQL alkalmazást Git-tel az Azure-ba 2"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9 main_hir_box_data_div">
            <h2 class="main_hir_title_list"><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/hir/12/igy-fejleszthetsz-egy-php-sql-alkalmazast-git-tel-az-azure-ba" title="Így fejleszthetsz egy PHP-SQL alkalmazást Git-tel az Azure-ba 2" class="main_hir_title_link_list">Így fejleszthetsz egy PHP-SQL alkalmazást Git-tel az Azure-ba 2</a></h2>
            <span class="main_hir_box_date">HÍREK | 2017-03-15 16:27</span>
            <p class="main_hir_box_desc">A bemutató feltételezi, hogy a gépeden már fel van telepítve a PHP, az SQL Server Express kiadása, valamint a Microsoft SQL Server meghajtói a PHP-hez és a Git verziókezelő is. A cikk során a következőket fogjuk megtanulni:</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row main_hir_box">
          <div class="col-md-3 main_hir_box_thumb_div">
            <a href="https://kemenyem.hu/hir/11/oriasposzteren-mutatja-be-a-visual-studio-2017-ujdonsagait-a-microsoft" title="Óriásposzteren mutatja be a Visual Studio 2017 újdonságait a Microsoft" class="main_hir_img_link"><img src="https://kemenyem.hu/images/news/th_s1600_0815_km_01-12894.jpg" class="img-responsive main_hir_img imageHoverOpacity" alt="Óriásposzteren mutatja be a Visual Studio 2017 újdonságait a Microsoft"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9 main_hir_box_data_div">
            <h2 class="main_hir_title_list"><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/hir/11/oriasposzteren-mutatja-be-a-visual-studio-2017-ujdonsagait-a-microsoft" title="Óriásposzteren mutatja be a Visual Studio 2017 újdonságait a Microsoft" class="main_hir_title_link_list">Óriásposzteren mutatja be a Visual Studio 2017 újdonságait a Microsoft</a></h2>
            <span class="main_hir_box_date">HÍREK | 2017-03-15 16:25</span>
            <p class="main_hir_box_desc">A Microsoft a hét elején Visual Studio blogjában egy olyan, általa poszternek hívott dokumentumot tett közzé, amelyben múlt héten bemutatott új integrált fejlesztői környezete legfontosabb újdonságait mutatja be. A máshol csak infografikának
              hívott összeállításban az általános, produktivitást javító fejlesztések mellett unit-tesztelést segítő újdonságok, sőt, a C++, a C# és az ASP.NET újdonságai is említésre kerülnek.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row main_hir_box">
          <div class="col-md-3 main_hir_box_thumb_div">
            <a href="https://kemenyem.hu/hir/10/uj-korszakot-nyit-a-most-elkeszult-llvm-es-a-clang-4-0" title="Új korszakot nyit a most elkészült LLVM és a Clang 4.0" class="main_hir_img_link"><img src="https://kemenyem.hu/images/news/th_p-dsc04186-81966.jpg" class="img-responsive main_hir_img imageHoverOpacity" alt="Új korszakot nyit a most elkészült LLVM és a Clang 4.0"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9 main_hir_box_data_div">
            <h2 class="main_hir_title_list"><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/hir/10/uj-korszakot-nyit-a-most-elkeszult-llvm-es-a-clang-4-0" title="Új korszakot nyit a most elkészült LLVM és a Clang 4.0" class="main_hir_title_link_list">Új korszakot nyit a most elkészült LLVM és a Clang 4.0</a></h2>
            <span class="main_hir_box_date">HÍREK | 2017-03-15 16:24</span>
            <p class="main_hir_box_desc">Az LLVM fejlesztői a napokban &quot;final&quot; jelöléssel látták el az LLVM és a Clang következő, 4-es verzióját. Bár a hivatalos bejelentés és a csomagok közzétételére vélhetően csak ezen a héten kerül majd sor, a fordító-infrastruktúra
              és a hozzá kapcsolódó C/C++ fordító legújabb kiadása ezzel elkészültnek tekinthető.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right_side">
      <div class="left_title_div">
        <h3 class="left_title">Hírlevél</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar_data_div">
        <div class="sidebar_data">
          <p class="sidebar_text">Iratkozzon fel hírlevelünkre, hogy mindíg értesüljön az újdonsgokról, friss hírekről.</p>
          <form action="files/newsletter.php" method="post" id="SidebarNewsletterForm">
            <input type="text" id="newsletterName" name="NewsletterName" placeholder="Az Ön neve" class="form-control sidebar_input">
            <input type="text" id="NewsletterEmail" name="NewsletterEmail" placeholder="E-mail címe" class="form-control sidebar_input">
            <button type="button" id="NewsletterButton" name="NewsletterButton" class="sidebar_button"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Feliratkozás</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer-basic-centered">
    <p class="footer-links">
      <a class="footer_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/" title="Kezdőlap">Kezdőlap</a><a class="footer_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/informaciok" title="Információk">Információk</a><a class="footer_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/erdekessegek"
        title="Hírek, érdekességek">Hírek, érdekességek</a><a class="footer_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kapcsolat" title="Kapcsolat">Kapcsolat</a><a class="footer_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/arlista" title="Árlista">Árlista</a>
      <a
        class="footer_menu_to_link" href="https://kemenyem.hu/galeria" title="Galéria">Galéria</a>
    </p>
    <p class="footer-company-name">2017 <br />
      <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: k_nev in <b>/home/grashu/public_html/kemenyem.hu/files/footer.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br /> &copy; - Minden jog fentartva!</p>
  </footer>
  <div class="modal fade" id="newsletterModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Bezárás</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Értesítés</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p id="newsletterResult"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="scrollToTop" title="Oldal tetejére"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up scrollToTopIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></body>
```

Hope this helps!